# How to use x editable to edit multiple fields in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm currently editing a single field in Laravel using the X-editable library.

But I want to do this for multiple fields without having to create new routes and methods in my controller, if it is possible. How can I accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<td data-url="/subjects/update/{{$subject->id}}" data-id="{{$subject->id}}" data-type="text" data-name="{{$subject->name}}" class="name" data-pk="{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</td>
```

route:

```
Route::post('/subjects/update/{id}', 'SubjectsController@update');
```

controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);
    $subject->name = $request->value;
    //$subject->level = $request->level;
    $subject->save();
    return response ()->json ( $subject );
}
```

script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('#subjects').editable({
    container:'body',
    selector:'td.name',
    type:'post',
    validate:function(value){
        if ($.trim(value) === '') {
            return "Field is required";
        }
    }
});
```

This is the level field that I want to edit also:

```
<td data-url="/subjects/update/{{$subject->id}}" data-id="{{$subject->id}}" data-type="text" data-name="{{$subject->level}}" class="level" data-pk="{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->level}}</td>
```

and this is how the script for it looks:

```
$('#subjects').editable({
    container:'body',
    selector:'td.level',
    type:'post',
    validate:function(value){
        if ($.trim(value) === '') {
            return "Field is required";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @chanafdo for the edit.